# jQuery DataTables pagination is not working when in IFRAME

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10.10 and the pagination works fine when accessing the page directly, however, it needs to be accessed via an iframe (as it is to show in sharepoint) and when it is in an iframe the pagination does not work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It works fine for me in iframe, see https://jsfiddle.net/ncykt2au/

Comment: it seems that it is not playing nicely with sharepoint then